# How to calculate the percentage of npm dependency usage in NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

Is there a way to calculate how many lines of code were actually triggered and used from an npm dependency defined in my project (`package.json`), regardless of how the dependency is imported later in project (the whole library or just a part of it)?

What I would like to achieve is to see if a dependency is worth of installing or not in some fairly big project I have, for example, if there's only 1% of library used, then it's maybe better to just write those few lines of code myself than rely on the whole library and its dependencies.

Comment: minified scripts are only one line of code so... seems like you'd need another metric :)... perhaps more of a "function" usage analysis

Comment: I would like to inspect this during the development phase, before minifying anything. I believe that majority of installed npm dependencies are not minified by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution that involves some minor hacks, but works pretty well.

The idea is to use a code coverage tool and use it to inspect `node_modules` as well, in addition to your code.

[nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) seems to be a popular code coverage module, so I went ahead and installed it: `npm install -g nyc`

I created a small example using 2 dependencies:

*index.js*

```
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp')
const ejs = require('ejs')

ejs.render('test');
mkdirp('.');
```

Running `nyc node index.js` only gives the coverage for index.js, which is not what we want:

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

It seems like `nyc` doesn't descend into `node_modules` and there is no way to configure it to do so. This issue was raised in their Github repository as well: [Include certain node modules #833](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/833)
Fortunately, someone gave a workaround: manually modify `test-exclude`, a dependency for nyc.

This is how I managed to get it working:

- Find the global installation folder for `nyc` (mine is: `C:\Users\mihai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nyc`)
- Within this folder, go to `node_modules\test-exclude` and edit `index.js`
- Find this array:

  ```
  exportFunc.defaultExclude = [
    ...
    '**/node_modules/**'
  ]
  ```

  Modify `'**/node_modules/**'` to `'**/nyc/node_modules/**'`
- Comment out these lines:

  ```
    if (this.exclude.indexOf('**/node_modules/**') === -1) {
       this.exclude.push('**/node_modules/**')
    }
  ```

Now everything is set, and we can run `nyc node index.js` again:

```
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                   |    42.75 |    29.34 |    40.48 |    43.03 |                   |
 myapp                      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.js                  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 myapp/node_modules/ejs/lib |    42.37 |     28.5 |    36.11 |    42.37 |                   |
  ejs.js                    |     42.2 |    29.32 |    44.44 |     42.2 |... 06,910,911,912 |
  utils.js                  |    44.44 |    11.11 |    11.11 |    44.44 |... 42,156,159,162 |
 myapp/node_modules/mkdirp  |    41.07 |    33.33 |    66.67 |    43.14 |                   |
  index.js                  |    41.07 |    33.33 |    66.67 |    43.14 |... 87,90,92,93,97 |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Note the coverage for `ejs.js` and `mkdirp`, showing Statements, Branches, Functions and Lines.

Comment: Oh, terribly sorry, didn't see your answer up until now :/ But this is amazing, even more than I expected, I'll give my best to test it out today already!!

Comment: Thank you very very much, this was exactly what I needed!